# Network Printer - Connect and Install Driver for Toshiba e-Studio3505AC

Tags: 14.04, drivers, printing

I am trying to connect to a network printer that is a Toshiba e-Studio3505AC. At first I tried doing it through `System Settings > Printers > Add > Network Printer > Find Network Printer`. I entered the host address but wasn't sure what to select for `Connection`. Based on what I was able to find online, it seems that it is supposed to be one of the `LPD/LPR queue` options; but which one isn't clear. Based on other things I found online, I assumed it was `LPD/LPR queue ''`. Clicked `Forward`. When using `Select printer from database`, I select `Toshiba (recommended)` then click `Forward`. I look though the list and it isn't there. When using `Search for a printer driver to download`, it just finds Toshiba e-Studio350. So I figured I needed the PPD.

I tried to get the PPD by going to [the support page](http://business.toshiba.com/support/downloads/index.html?model=e-STUDIO3505AC). I downloaded `linux.tar` (which is not the PPD as far as I can tell) and then tried to follow the instructions in the [installation guide](http://business.toshiba.com/downloads/KB/f1Ulds/15806/eS5008A_USIG_EN_0004.pdf).

Here are the two issues.

1. The shell script wants me to restart my lpd. However, I am having trouble finding directions on how to do that. I can find a lot about lpd including the manpage, discussions of what it is, etc. but nothing about how to restart it.
2. The installation guide says the linux users still need to add the printer via the OS's printer management tool. I am assuming that is what I used in my earlier attempts. When I do that, there is no change in what happens.

Comment: facing exactly same issue.. did you find a solution?

Comment: @rok Unfortunately, no. I never got this issue resolved. The computer I was trying to connect was a dual-boot with Windows 7 so I eventually ended up just saving to a common drive, booting into Windows, and printing from there. Not at all convenient but better than no being able to print at all.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I recently had to set up a TOSHIBA e-Studio 4515ac on Mint 20 and couldn't find complete instructions (Toshiba's instructions are good but sometimes vague and incomplete)--so I decided to answer this in case it helps someone else. Here's how I got the printer installed:

1. Download the official driver and (for reference) the "Software Installation Guide". I got mine here: https://business.toshiba.com/support/downloads/index.html?model=4515ac.
2. Unzip the driver package somewhere (in this example this is indicated by **<DRIVER_DIR>**), then copy the needed archives to root:

   ```
   $ cp <DRIVER_DIR>/LinuxFilter/Usa/linux.tar <DRIVER_DIR>/CUPS/Usa/normal/TOSHIBA_ColorMFP_CUPS.tar /
   ```
3. 'Install' the packages (Toshiba has compressed their package archives with the full paths, so extracting them from root puts the files in their proper place):

   ```
   $ cd /  
   $ sudo tar xvf linux.tar  
   ...  
   $ sudo tar xvf TOSHIBA_ColorMFP_CUPS.tar  
   ...
   ```
4. Install the printer description and create the queue using Toshiba's `estcoloradd` utility:

   ```
   $ sudo estcoloradd <QUEUE_NAME> <PRINTER_DNS_NAME/IP>  
   $ sudo systemctl restart cups
   ```

   (BTW I got a warning when I did this, but it did not effect the setup.)
5. Setup the PPD file (because there was no PPD extension on the original extracted file, Mint wouldn't recognize it in my case):

   ```
   $ cd /usr/share/cups/model/Toshiba/  
   $ sudo gunzip TOSHIBA_ColorMFP_CUPS.gz  
   $ sudo mv TOSHIBA_ColorMFP_CUPS TOSHIBA_ColorMFP_CUPS.ppd
   ```

   Toshiba's docs say to re-gzip the file, but this isn't necessary.

   I also changed the model number to match my printer, but I don't think this is necessary either. In case you want to do this, edit `/usr/share/cups/model/Toshiba/TOSHIBA_ColorMFP_CUPS.ppd` and change the model number to match your printer in this line (replace the '**XXXX**' part):

   ```
   *cupsFilter: "application/vnd.cups-postscript 0 /usr/lib/cups/filter/Toshiba/estXXXX_Authentication"
   ```

   Also rename the file this line refers to here:

   ```
   /usr/lib/cups/filter/estXXXX_Authentication
   ```

   (In any case, make sure those match.)
6. Install the printer with the GUI printer utility:

   Pick "LPD/LPR Host or Printer" and use the info from step 4 for 'host' and 'queue'. Then manually choose the PPD (`/usr/share/cups/model/Toshiba/TOSHIBA_ColorMFP_CUPS.ppd`) to complete the setup.